# What will be the equivalent of following code in kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, webview

Here is a Java code I found in a library and I am using kotlin. But I yet don't know how to convert it to kotlin.

```
  myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: "*But I'm unable to convert it to kotlin.*" - Why not? What is the problem? Please show your attempt(s) and ask a more specific question.

Comment: I'm sorry if it was not clear. Thank you so much for your comment. next time i will really be more careful!

Comment: Vague title. Edit to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: @Basil Bourque, haha. I may be a clickbait guy. Anyway, sorry for the title. can you suggest anything that you think would be better for this question title. I really need to learn this stuff. thanks for your comment anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myWebView.setWebChromeClient(object : WebChromeClient() {
            override fun onCreateWindow(view: WebView, isDialog: Boolean, isUserGesture: Boolean, resultMsg: Message): Boolean {
                return true
            }
        })
```